# Android Keylogger

Tags: android, keylogger

I am writing an application for the Android for an examination. One of the features of the application is the keylogger that captures everything that user types. I didn't understand how I could implement the functionality of keylogger, if is possible to catch everything a user types and unfortunately I found very little code in the network. 
Can anyone help me? Thanks for the attention

Comment: You can't. An app does not see input besides the input targeted at itself.

Answer (score 7):

I might be wrong but I believe that your application can catch only those inputs which were made inside the application. I do not think Android gives you the ability to capture all the key events in all the applications, from your application. So, you can get only those key-events which were targeted to your application in particular..

**EDIT :** I looked around on the internet and it seems that there a few *unethical* ways of doing this. You can create your **own custom keyboard** and catch the inputs from there. Another way of achieving this would be to run a **`service`** in the background with a **`KeyListener`** activity to catch the key-events.

Comment: thanks, i' try to run a service in the background with a KeyListener activity to catch the key-events.

Comment: Yeah, do that. And feel free to paste your code and ask for help if you get stuck in the process. Good luck! :)

Comment: @fra : And do accept the answer if it was of any help. Cheers! :)