# How do I launch an app with physical camera key or mic key - android?

Tags: android

I am developing a simple app for a 4G flip phone that will emulate a home button press (and show the launcher) when the phone's mic key or camera key is pressed while the phone's InCall Activity is topmost. (There is no home button on this phone, and the inability to return to the home screen is really frustrating.) When i use adb to send an intent calling the homescreen to the front while in call, it works, but I am trying to make an app for it so that i can do it on the go.
My trouble is assigning the app to be launched by a key press (the camera key or the mic key) while the native InCallActivity is on top. Can I do this via the XML for a reciever, and how? or do I need a service that scans for a keypress? And is what I am want potentially considered malware?
In short, can this be achieved safely and efficiently, and how?

Comment: you cannot hijack keys from other apps,let alone system keys, let alone system apps. it would be chaos and the very definition of malware .

Comment: thats very understandable, however i am open to assigning keyboard shortcuts etc, that require user authorization. i just want to know if there is any way possible, even if the user has to set it up themselves. also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432498/android-keylogger/12432611#12432611), but am trying to avoid something like that

Comment: I don't know if that would work tbh... a custom keyboard seems overkill, and a service that read keys I am still not convinced if it would allow to read all keys if the launching activity is not foreground (new background services restrictions https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes) I 'd bet it won't work! (otherwise why won't be all apps manipulating your banking account keypresses?)

Comment: can i set the camera key to redirect to my app though, instead, like a shortcut key. does android have built in support for app-launch shortcut keys, or does it depend on the launcher?